# WCF REST Service EndPoint not found error with WebInvoke

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF REST service. I verified Webconfig file and all config items are fine.

I am getting EndPoint not found error with below code. I will add parameters to GetDateTime method.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] 
    string GetDateTime();
```

NO Endpoint error with below code.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
string GetDateTime();
```

I want to get this running with WebInvoke. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the config details from Web.config file.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SampleRest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration ="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding ="webHttpBinding" contract="SampleRest.IService1" behaviorConfiguration ="web" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior  name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Here is the URL that I tried.

http://localhost:65317/Service1.svc

Comment: Could you post your config and the url you try to get to the WebGet method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following code:

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string PostDateTimeAndReturnAsString(DateTime dateTime);
```

The implementation of the above method as shown below:

```
public string PostDateTimeAndReturnAsString(DateTime dateTime)
{
       return dateTime.ToString();
}
```

My web.config as shown below:

```
<services>
    <service name="XMLService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="default">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" name="Service1" contract="XMLService.IService1" />
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
         <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My raw request from fiddler as below:

```
POST http://localhost/XMLService/Service1.svc/postdatetimeandreturnasstring HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 30

"\/Date(1330081170513+0000)\/"
```

I get back the a HTTP 200 OK code with the following response back:

```
"24\/02\/2012 11:07:59"
```

NOTE: when date time is a parameter that needs to be passed in json format that is the way you need to pass it as shown in the raw request format ( the value that i used was during my execution the current date time, using the same value should return the value as shown below)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whole `system.serviceModel` from the config as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and I assume your SVC file already looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
                Language="C#" Service="SampleRest.Service1" 
                Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

svc automatically do the configuration within `system.serviceModel` for you.

at last try http://localhost:65317/Service1.svc/

Answer (score 0):

You should call the operation itself. In your example, your client has to point to:

```
http://localhost:65317/Service1.svc/GetDateTime
```

That will work, providing you web.config is well defined